# Using sklearn to find the coefficents of each group of a dataframe

Tags: python, group-by, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe (df1) with some values and multiple groups. I would like to perform a linear regression on each group, so I can use the coefficients to complete df2 and then concatenate them (df3).
 So far I have manger to it on my whole dataframe doing

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import pandas as pd

def ols (X, y):
    return linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X, y)

X = df1[["day"]]
y = df1["value"]

results = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(df1[["day"]], df1["value"])

df2['value'] = results.coef_*df2['day']+results.intercept_

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

This works but when I try use groupby and apply like `result = df1.groupby('id').apply(ols(df1[["day"]], df1["value"]))` I get an error `TypeError: 'LinearRegression' object is not callable`
I understand that I haven't initialized an instance of the LinearRegression class but how can I do it using groupby?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                    'day' : [179,194, 184, 194],
                    'value' :  [0.667, 1.229, 1.079, 1.69 ]
                            })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'b'],
                    'day' : [191, 192],
                    'value' :  ['lai', 'lai']
                            })

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'a','a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                    'day' : [179,191, 194, 184, 192, 194],
                    'value' :  [0.667, 1.1166, 1.229, 1.079,1.5678,, 1.69 ]
                            })
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues here:

1. pandas `apply()` need a function as input, not the returned value of function, so you can only do:

   ```
   df1.groupby('id').apply(ols)
   ```

   and not like what you did. `ols(df1[["day"]], df1["value"])` returns a `LinearRegression` object which is not accepted by `apply` and hence the error.
2. `groupby('id').apply(...)` will apply the supplied function on the parts of dataframe according to the groups in the `df`. So you cannot simply supply the whole data `df1[["day"]], df1["value"]` to the `ols` method and expect it to fit according to different groups.

Other than that the question is very unclear. What do you exactly want to do? Do you want to use your `df1` as training data on which you want to learn the coefficients for each group ('id') and then use them to predict the values in the `df2` for the same `'id'`?

Comment: Yes I want to use ```df1``` as training data and use the coefficients to predict the values in ```df2``` for each group.

Comment: If I do ```def ols_res(df1, xcols,  ycol):
   model = LinearRegression()
   return model.fit(df1[ycol], df1[xcols])``` and ```  results = df1.groupby('id').apply(ols_res, xcol=['value'], ycol=['day']) ``` I can use ```for i in results:
    print (i.intercept_)
    print(i.coef_)``` I can see that I have the good coefficients for each group but I don't know how to store them and then use them. I know I should use model.predict() but I don't understand how.